# iPad UIActionSheet tap outside to dismiss - state of UIActionSheet?

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet, sharekit

I am using the ShareKit SHKActionSheet (based on UIActionSheet) for an app on the iPad:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@""];
actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

I want to perform some action depending on whether actionSheet is in view or not. The problem is that when a user taps outside actionSheet to dismiss it from view (default behaviour on iPad) actionSheet no longer points to a valid SHKActionSheet nor does it have a nil value. How can I test for such a dismiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIActionSheet` class has a `visible` property. This returns `YES` if the action sheet is showing, `NO` if it isn't. That should enable you to know whether or not it's been dismissed.

You could also implement some `UIActionSheetDelegate` methods to know when it's been dismissed or cancelled using `actionSheetCancel:` and/or `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`.

**EDIT:**

To be sure to receive the delegate calls of your UIActionSheet, be sure to indicate in your controller's interface declaration (.h):

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate>

@end
```

Then in the controller's implementation (.m) :

```
- (void)actionSheetCancel:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

    NSLog(@"action sheet is about to be cancelled");
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"action sheet was dismissed");
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've just had a look at the code of the `SHKActionSheet` class and it turns out it doesn't implement the `actionSheetCancel:` method, which is why you're not receiving it. It does, however, implement the `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method :

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Sharers
    if (buttonIndex >= 0 && buttonIndex < sharers.count)
    {
        [NSClassFromString([sharers objectAtIndex:buttonIndex]) performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
    }

    // More
    else if (buttonIndex == sharers.count)
    {
        SHKShareMenu *shareMenu = [[SHKCustomShareMenu alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        shareMenu.item = item;
        [[SHK currentHelper] showViewController:shareMenu];
        [shareMenu release];
    }

    [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
}
```

If you want to be notified of the `actionSheetCancel:` method, simply add this to the SHKActionSheet.m file :

```
- (void)actionSheetCancel:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

    [super actionSheetCancel:actionSheet];
}
```

The delegate method in your controller will then be called properly :)

[UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIActionSheetDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006799)

Comment: The problem is that the app crashes when I test actionSheet.visible after it has been dismissed.

Comment: Ok, in that case try implementing the delegate methods I mentioned. Make sure you set the action sheet's delegate property: `actionSheet.delegate = self;`

Comment: In my setup I do the following:  
SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:nil
destructiveButtonTitle:nil
otherButtonTitles:nil];

but the delegate line is giving me a warning that self is not of type UIActionSheetDelegate. I think this is stopping me from setting up delegates.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer to show how to use the delegate methods

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I didn't get those delegates to work. However, it lead me to put an NSlog in dismissWithClickedButtonIndex which in fact does get called after a dimiss (the "ClickedButton" part was misleading).

Comment: You're welcome. I edited again in case you'd rather use the `actionSheetCancel:` method instead of the `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:` method